# Make the font used to show user reputation in posts a little more readable?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, design

First of all, I think the new design is amazing. It elegantly combines the fantasy and sci-fi settings that tend to be prominent in RPG's, and also uses the pencil drawings at the bottom corners of the header to help show that this site is for pencil and paper RPGs and NOT video-game RPGs like World of Warcraft.

So far, the only thing I've noticed that I dislike is the font that shows user reputation in posts. The 3's and 5's just seem to blend in with the adjacent numbers a little, which makes them harder to read. Granted, this is an extreme nitpick in the amazing design, and I'll probably get used to it over time, but I wanted to see if anybody else agreed with me about the decrease in legibility. :D

Comment: I can tweak that.

Comment: On a related note the "X" seems to be a lot bigger than the other lower case letters in the username font...

Answer (score 1):

I changed the badge count and reputation numbers to a different serif type and increased the size a bit. The change should be in the next production build.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again for creating yet another great SE site design. ;)